how to find the singular values of singular value decomposition (SVD)
I am a bit confused as to how we find the singular values and therefore condition index number. Some mathematicians say the singular values are the square roots of the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix of the predictors of a model. While others says we use covariance matrix instead. Again some math publications said The singular values are the square roots of the eigenvalues of the square matrix X'X of multiple linear regression model. For convenience I tried doing all three where
Correlation Matrix =     1      0.83863  -0.46207   -0.6500
0.83863       1    -0.2796    -0.3557
-0.46207   -0.2796      1       0.06494
-0.6500    -0.3557  0.06494       1
Covariance Matrix = 63.2027    83.5845   -23.49923    -86.503653
83.5845   157.1722   -22.4221     -74.650134
-23.49923  -22.4221   40.92201633  6.9541
-86.503653 -74.650134  6.9541      280.240857
X'X =  49         947.7         2617.27     49647.57        3389.13
947.7     21426.2236    54715.7778    959073.0701     61309.8618
2617.27    54715.7778    147499.4441   2650760.4091    177368.0266
49647.57   959073.0701   2650760.4091  50305703.2789   3434260.5237
3389.13   61309.8618    177368.0266   3434260.5237    248144.0909
Thank you!

What programming environment are you using? It's true that there's a relationship between the singular values of a matrix and that matrix's eigenvalues (if it has any), but numerically it is best to directly compute the singular values rather than going through the eigenvalues as an intermediary. In R, we use "svd" while in python we use "np.linalg.svd" to do this. You apply svd directly to $\mathbf{X}$; no need to form a covariance/gram matrix.

We have many discussions of this.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=svd%20eigenvalue&searchOn=3.  You might find https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259890/, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/479485, or even https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154335/ to be especially pertinent to your implied question.  Indeed, what is your question?  You have only stated you are "confused."  We can't give an answer to that!

wait you cant see the whole question? It only displays I am confused? I wrote this "how we find the singular values and therefore condition index number. Some mathematicians say the singular values are the square roots of the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix of the predictors of a model. While others says we use covariance matrix instead. Again some math publications said The singular values are the square roots of the eigenvalues of the square matrix X'X of multiple linear regression model.

I didnt understand when you said "you have only stated I am confused". My entrie question is not visible?

I still see no question explicitly stated in your comments or your post--only implied questions.  You need to be clear about what you wish to ask.
